# The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference sending HL7 Message

Tags: hl7, mirth

All

I am new in mirth when i sending a hl7 message to Mirth Http Listener, I get a Exception

The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

What HTTP Listener settings, inbound data type, and sample message are you using? Also, export and post/pastebin your channel here; it makes troubleshooting much easier.